# Proper way to verify Google Access Token? [React Oauth Google]

Tags: reactjs, oauth, google-oauth

When using a custom login button in the '@react-oauth/google' react package, I am given an "access token" that this guide (https://livefiredev.com/in-depth-guide-sign-in-with-google-in-a-react-js-application/) says the client should pass to the backend server. The server then makes a request to "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>" to get information like this:

```
{
  "id": "102592121061571384",
  "email": "someemail@gmail.com",
  "verified_email": true,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "given_name": "John",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ALm5wu32meinHR2EEwUYP1qnwbfH8N2cfy_qHm-=s96-c",
  "locale": "en-GB"
}
```

But nothing in this request guarantees that this token is for my server/application. What is preventing me from taking this access_token and giving it to any other application that uses a similar authentication method?

I am asking because the same package provides a default button GoogleLogin, which has a different login process wherein a jwt "credential" is provided, which contains a signature unique to my application that my backend can verify. Unfortunately, a custom button doesn't seem to have this feature.